# Java 8 Streams: Collapse/abstract streams parts

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say I have this Stream:

```
list.stream()
    .map(fn1)      // part1
    .map(fn2)      // 
    .filter(fn3)   // 

    .flatMap(fn4)  // part 2 
    .map(fn5)      //
    .filter(fn6)   //
    .map(fn7)      //
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

How can I make it look like:

```
list.stream()
    .map(fnPart1)      
    .map(fnPart2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Without manually unwinding the fnX parts and putting them together (for maintenance reasons, I want to keep them untouched, and express the fnPartX with them).

Comment: Map, unlike flatMap and filter, cannot change the number of items in the stream.

Comment: @BenoitParis I may have misunderstood the question but you could assign part1 to a `Stream<String>` and part2 to a `Stream<Object>` and then call collect on the `Stream<Object>`?

Comment: You can't. At least, you can't do it the way you want (with two functions, using `map` on the initial stream). This is because `map()` works on the stream *elements* (it transforms each element of the stream, not the stream itself), so you can't i.e. filter elements, which is an operation over the stream itself (it removes some elements based on a condition).

Comment: Are part 1 and part 2 fixed? I mean, are they always the same, i.e. is part1 `map(fn1)`, then `map(fn2)` and then `filter(fn3)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could express and compose it with functions:

```
Function<Stream<T1>, Stream<T2>> fnPart1 = 
        s -> s.map(fn1)
            .map(fn2) 
            .filter(fn3);
Function<Stream<T2>, Stream<T3>> fnPart2 = 
        s -> s.flatMap(fn4)
            .map(fn5)      
            .filter(fn6)   
            .map(fn7);

fnPart1.andThen(fnPart2).apply(list.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The input and output types of the functions have to match accordingly.

This can be the basis for a more complex composition construct such as:

```
public class Composer<T>{
    private final T element;

    private Composer(T element){
        this.element = element;
    }

    public <T2> Composer<T2> andThen(Function<? super T, ? extends T2> f){
        return new Composer<>(f.apply(element));
    }

    public T get(){
        return element;
    }

    public static <T> Composer<T> of(T element){
        return new Composer<T>(element);
    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
Composer.of(list.stream())
    .andThen(fnPart1)
    .andThen(fnPart2)
    .get()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That `Composer` could probably be more generic, so that it can be used with more than just streams. It reminds me of `Optional`.

Comment: @4castle You are right. The `Composer` does not use any stream specific properties - I edited it. It is just an attempt to bring the composition of the functions into a structure that looks similar to what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I was worrying about needing to materialize the thing in between, but andThen lets us compose Functions.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use flatMap not map. I don't know what your types are so I've called them T1, T2, etc.

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(fnPart1)      
    .flatMap(fnPart2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())

Stream<T2> fnPart1(T1 t1) {
    return Stream.of(t1).map(fn1).map(fn2).filter(fn3);
}

Stream<T3> fnPart2(T2 t2) {
    return Stream.of(t2).flatMap(fn4).map(fn5).filter(fn6).map(fn7);
}
```

Of course you could remove some of the stream operations:

```
Stream<T2> fnPart1(T1 t1) {
    return Stream.of(fn2(fn1(t1))).filter(fn3);
}

Stream<T3> fnPart2(T2 t2) {
    return fn4(t2).map(fn5).filter(fn6).map(fn7);
}
```

Further simplification is possible since fnPart1 and fnPart2 are just dealing with single elements.